# How do I change date and time formats in Trello?

Tags: trello, formatting

How do I change the formatting of time and dates in Trello?

I'm looking to change the following:

- time presentation to 24 hour clock instead of 12
- date format to DD/MM/YY instead of MM/DD/YY?

Comment: This is absolutely essential, as most users outside of the US use the 24 hour clock and DD/MM/YYYY format. It's very frustrating having to spend time working out what date is being represented.

Answer (score 7):

Change your language settings to English (UK) in your Atlassian account and you will get 24-hour time settings.

Comment: Have you tested this?

Comment: @serenesat That's work for me

Comment: Or, in reverse. Change it to US to get 12-hour time

Comment: I can confirm this works for me, too, also stated here: https://help.trello.com/article/813-a

Comment: Not working here. I changed to English UK, and the due-date button on each card still shows a calendar with am/pm and mm-dd-yyyy.

Answer (score 6):

Changing date formats is not currently possible. Selecting from the date picker will automatically format the date, though.

Comment: If I had 2 more rep points, I'd be able to -1 this, for the reason that I've posted above.

Comment: I was just stating that it's not currently possible. It's something the team wants to support eventually.

Comment: `not currently possible` does kind of imply that, I must have missed the word 'currently' when I first read it, as I somehow got the impression it wasn't going to be implemented. Apologies and +1.

Comment: But you can still set e.g. deadline time using 24h format, it accepts that too.

Comment: The problem with the 12 hours format is that is is at best ambiguous, at worst wrong: as explained on http://www.nist.gov/pml/div688/times.cfm#noon 00:00 should be formatted 12:00 midnight and 12:00 should be formatted 12:00 noon, as per the US NIST.

However, currently (3 years after that answer), entering either 12:00 noon or 12:00 midnight is always translated as 12:00 pm, leaving the actual interpretation unknown.

Comment: ISO 8601 should be supported (YYYY-MM-DD, YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm, ) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601

Comment: Is it possible already? This answer is from what, 2011? We are in 2021 now. I changed to English UK, but the due-date button on each card is still am/pm and date is still MM-DD-YY.

Answer (score 1):

Change done from Atlassian account

Steps:

1. In Trello click on your **User Icon** on right top corner > **Settings**
2. In **Account Details**, press **Change Language** (Atlassian credentials will be required here and Atlassian settings will be opened in new tab)
3. Language set by default to "English US" - Change it to "**English UK**"
4. **Close your Trello** tab in browser (Important!!!) and open again

Now, when you open card and go to Dates, you should see format DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM without AM PM

Note: I tested and it worked for me but changes takes effect only after reopening Trello board

Comment: +1 It's important to close trello and reopen it for changes to work (point 4 in the answer)